# Check if Player X or Player Y has won function/module. Tic Tac Toe

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Hello** ! I have a **question** guys.

I was writing my first serious python training project because I'm beginner but I encountered a problem that stops me from further development of my program.

**I don't have idea how can I write *function/module* in my class that check if player X or player Y has won. I tried on so many different ways but it seems to not work. *I know that the my code is looking awful. Thank you for your time spent.***

```
import sys

class Tic_tac_toe():

    def __init__(self):
        self.board = {'top-L': ' ', 'top-M': ' ', 'top-R': ' ',
                      'mid-L': ' ', 'mid-M': ' ', 'mid-R': ' ',
                      'low-L': ' ', 'low-M': ' ', 'low-R': ' '}
        self.move_X = None
        self.move_0 = None
        self.WINNING_MOVE = None
        self.loop = None
        self.nameX = None
        self.nameO = None
        self.choice = None

    def welcome(self):
        try:
            print("Welcome ! :)\n\nWho is PLAYER X ? :")
            self.nameX = input()
            print("\nWho is PLAYER O ? :")
            self.nameO = input()
            print("\nHello {} and {}, ready to play? (Y/N) :".format(self.nameX.title(), self.nameO.title()))
            self.choice = input()
            if self.choice.title() == 'N' or '\n':
                sys.exit()
            print('\n{} is PLAYER X.\n{} is PLAYER Y.'.format(self.nameX.title(),self.nameO.title()))
        except ValueError:
            print('\nTry again:\n')


    def printBoard(self):
        print()
        print(self.board['top-L'] + '|' + self.board['top-M'] + '|' + self.board['top-R'])
        print('-+-+-')
        print(self.board['mid-L'] + '|' + self.board['mid-M'] + '|' + self.board['mid-R'])
        print('-+-+-')
        print(self.board['low-L'] + '|' + self.board['low-M'] + '|' + self.board['low-R'])
        print()

    def moves_X(self):
        try:
            self.move_X = int(input("Player X :\nChoose field (1,9) : "))
            self.write_on_boardX()
            self.printBoard()
        except ValueError:
            print("\nYOU DIDN'T ENTER NUMBER !\n")

    def moves_O(self):
        try:
            self.move_O = int(input("Player O :\nChoose field (1,9) : "))
            self.write_on_boardO()
            self.printBoard()
        except ValueError:
            print("\nYOU DIDN'T ENTER NUMBER!\n")

    def mix_XO(self):
        self.loop = 0
        for x in range(1,10):
            if self.loop % 2 == 0:
                self.moves_X()
                self.loop += 1
            elif self.loop % 2 == 1:
                self.moves_O()
                self.loop += 1

    def write_on_boardX(self):
        if self.move_X == 1:
            self.board['top-L'] = 'X'
        elif self.move_X == 2:
            self.board['top-M'] = 'X'
        elif self.move_X == 3:
            self.board['top-R'] = 'X'
        elif self.move_X == 4:
            self.board['mid-L'] = 'X'
        elif self.move_X == 5:
            self.board['mid-M'] = 'X'
        elif self.move_X == 6:
            self.board['mid-R'] = 'X'
        elif self.move_X == 7:
            self.board['low-L'] = 'X'
        elif self.move_X == 8:
            self.board['low-M'] = 'X'
        elif self.move_X == 9:
            self.board['low-R'] = 'X'

    def write_on_boardO(self):
        if self.move_O == 1:
            self.board['top-L'] = 'O'
        elif self.move_O == 2:
            self.board['top-M'] = 'O'
        elif self.move_O == 3:
            self.board['top-R'] = 'O'
        elif self.move_O == 4:
            self.board['mid-L'] = 'O'
        elif self.move_O == 5:
            self.board['mid-M'] = 'O'
        elif self.move_O == 6:
            self.board['mid-R'] = 'O'
        elif self.move_O == 7:
            self.board['low-L'] = 'O'
        elif self.move_O == 8:
            self.board['low-M'] = 'O'
        elif self.move_O == 9:
            self.board['low-R'] = '0'

    def winning_movesX(self):
        pass

def main():
    app = Tic_tac_toe()
    app.welcome()
    app.printBoard()
    app.mix_XO()

main()
```

Answer (score -1):

One way to achieve this is to first create a map of all the possible winning 'lines' and then see if the elements on that line are all the same, by creating a set and checking it contains only 1 item (`X` or `O`). For example:

```
lines = [
  ['top-L','top-M','top-R'],
  ['top-L', 'mid-L', 'low-L']
  ... etc ...
]

for line in lines:
    if len(set(self.board[x] for x in line])) == 1:
        print("Winner:", self.board[line[0]])
```

Answer (score -1):

#### Different Approach might be easier...

> A simpler way would be to use a 3x3 matrix, e.g. with:
>
> - `0` as a default value
> - `-1` for player 1
> - `+1` for player 2
>
> You can then calculate the sum of the rows/columns/diagonals. With -3 as a player 1 win, +3 as a player 2 win. For example by using numpy:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.zeros((3, 3), dtype=int)
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]])
```

=> `self.board = np.zeros((3,3), dtype=int)`

and a win check would roughly look like:

```
d1,d2 = 0,0 #used to calculate sum of diagonal 

for i in range(3):
    #check row
    if sum(self.board[i, :]) in (3,-3):
        self.win = True
    #check column
    elif sum(self.board[:, i]) in (3,-3):
        self.win = True
    #check diagonal
    d1 += self.board[i, i]   #diagonal from top left corner to bottom right corner
    d2 += self.board[i, 2-i] #diagonal from top right corner to bottom left corner
    elif d1 in (3,-3) or d2 in (-3,3):
        self.win = True
```

Note: You know which player has won since you know who's turn it was last.

---

Well, and since you seem to be rather new to python here a quick overview on how to access elements of an array:

```
>>> board = np.zeros((3,3), dtype=int)
>>> board[0][1] = 3
>>> board
array([[0, 3, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]])
```

And in case you keep this board:

```
"""
 [1] | [2] | [3]
-----------------
 [4] | [5] | [6]
-----------------
 [7] | [8] | [9]
"""
```

you could use the integer division `//` and the modulo function `%` instead of all the `elif` statements to determine what field/position on the board the user meant:

```
position = int(input("Choose position:"))

   row = (position-1)//3
column = (position-1)%3

self.board[row][column] = 1 #or -1
```

---

**P.S.:**
If you want to implement a "player vs. computer" later on, you might change the value -1 to -3 to get unique sum values. (-1 +1 +0 = 0 +0 +0)